# Why shouldn't I access elements more "directly" (elemId.innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've seen some JavaScript code to access HTML elements like this: `elementID.innerHTML`, and it works, though practically every tutorial I searched for uses `document.getElementById()`. I don't even know if there's a term for the short addressing.

At first I thought simplistically that each id'ed HTML element was directly under `window` but using `getParent()` shows the tree structure is there, so it didn't matter that elements I wanted were nested. I wrote a short test case:

http://jsfiddle.net/hYzLu/

```
<div id="fruit">Mango<div id="color">red</div></div>
<div id="car">Chevy</div>
<div id="result" style="color: #A33"></div>

result.innerHTML = "I like my " + color.innerHTML + " " + car.innerHTML;
```

The "short" method looks like a nice shortcut, but I feel there is something wrong with it for it practically not appearing in tutorials.

Why is `document.getElementById()` preferred, or may be even required in some cases?

Comment: Because Firefox doesn't support that.

Comment: It's not a standard specification.

Comment: Next time I'll remember to test across browsers before posting code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why shouldn't I access elements more “directly” (elemId.innerHTML)

Because, according to the others in this thread, **referencing arbitrarily by id name is not fully supported**.

So, what I think you should be doing instead is store their selections into a var, and then reference the var.

Try instead

```
var color = document.getElementById('color');
color.innerHTML = 'something';
```

The reason why this would be a good thing to do is that performing a lookup in the DOM is an expensive process, memory wise. And so if you store the element's reference into a variable, it becomes static. Thus you're not performing a lookup each time you want to `.doSomething()` to it.

Please note that javascript libraries tend to add shim functions to increase general function support across browsers. which would be a benefit to using, for example, jquery's selectors over pure javascript. Though, if you are in fact worried about memory / performance, native JS usually wins speed tests. (jsperf.com is a good tool for measuring speed and doing comparisons.)

Comment: Nah that's not what he is seeing, you can actually reference elements like that in JavaScript that have corresponding ID's in the DOM, good demonstration of object caching though :)

Comment: Haha tell me about it, it is **very** old school :)

Comment: It was in a short script that I saw `myId.innerHTML` though it's good to know about this memory-saving reference.

Comment: @HeitorChang yeah you gotta be careful with JavaScript, as there are many things that may work in one browser, but not in another. That's why I prefer jQuery personally, it provides methods to do the same things much cleaner, whilst also maintaining cross browser support :)

Answer (score 1):

It's *safer* I guess. If you had a variable named `result` in the same context that you are doing `result.HTML` I'm pretty sure the browser will throw a wobbler. Doing it in the way of `document.getElementById()` in this instance would obviously provide you with the associated DOM element.

Also, if you are dynamically adding HTML to the page I may be wrong, but you could also encounter unexpected behaviour in terms of what `result` is :)

Answer (score 1):

Also I will add that not all ID's can have values that will not work as variable names. For instance if your ID is "nav-menu".

Although I suppose you could write window["nav-menu"].innerHTML

Which makes me think, what happens if you create a window level variable with the same name as an ID? 
Checkout this jsfiddle (tested in chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/8yH5y/

This really seems like a bad idea altogether. Just use document.getElementById("id") and store the result to a variable if you will be using the reference more than once.